# Deleting record in MS Access using vb 2010

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagrid

I have connected my access database via adding data source in vb 2010. I also have datagrid that is also connected. The problem is whenever I delete a record it doesn't change in the ms access file but it changes in the datagrid. I have tried changing copy always to copy if newer but still it doesn't work. Please help me.

Here is the code:

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this data?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Inventory") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        BotikaBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    End If
```

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519195/how-to-delete-records-of-ms-access-database-using-vb-net-form-and-how-to-enter-a

Comment: You are clearly doing something wrong then but, as you haven't shown us what you're doing, we can't really tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: You should paste the **code** so that others can help you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've posted now my code.

Comment: That code only marks the local `DataRow` as deleted.  It doesn't do anything to the database.  Inserting, updating and deleting are all done locally first and the changes are then saved to the database by calling `Update` on your data adapter or table adapter.